# AMPScript - Name is just an initial, not blank

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have a few customers whose name is just an initial in the DE. I'd like to personalize the subject line but don't want "Dear A,..."

I have the code for if it were blank, but is there a way to check if there's <= 1 character THEN...?

This is what I have for blank:

```
%%[ 
IF EMPTY(first_name) 
THEN SET @subject = "Valued Customer" 
ELSE SET @ subject = first_name 
ENDIF ]%%
```

Thank you

Comment: You can find answer to your above query and similar code snippets here https://cvvishalkumar.github.io/sfmc-ninja/#ampscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [length](https://ampscript.guide/length) function and do something like this:

```ampscript
%%[ 

set @first_name = AttributeValue("first_name")

IF EMPTY(@first_name) or length(@first_name) == 1 THEN 
  SET @subject = "Valued Customer" 
ELSE 
  SET @subject = @first_name 
ENDIF 

]%%
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for and on testing, it works. Thank you!